# SQL conditional aggregation?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have the following table:

```
  name virtual message
--------------------------
  a       1     'm1'
  a       1     'm2'
  a       0     'm3'
  a       0     'm4'
  b       1     'm5'
  b       0     'm6'
  c       0     'm7'
```

I want to group by name but only concat the message if virtual is 1.

The result I am looking for is:

```
name  concat_message
---------------------
a         'm1,m2'
b            'm5'
c              ''
```

I couldn't find a way to conditionally aggregate using `string_agg`.

Comment: What RDBMS are you in?

Comment: you can add a `case` or `if` depending on your rbms inside the string_agg function something like `string_agg( case when virtual = 1 then virtual else '' end, ',')`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I am using bigquery in google cloud, the problem with that approach is that it will create additional comma for virtual != 0. For example, I will get something like this instead `a       'm1,m2,,'`

Comment: why is there a c value on your output?  c is not virtual 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL offers `listagg()` to aggregate strings.  So this looks something like:

```
select name,
       listagg(case when virtual = 1 then message end, ',') within group (order by message)
from t
group by name;
```

However, most databases have different names (and syntax) for string aggregation, such as `string_agg()` or `group_concat()`.

EDIT:

In BQ the syntax would be:

```
select name,
       string_agg(case when virtual = 1 then message end, ',')
from t
group by name;
```

That said, I would recommend `array_agg()` rather than `string_agg()`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select name, 
  ifnull(string_agg(if(virtual=1,message,null)), '') as concat_message
from your_table
group by name
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use xml xpath to rotate row data into a single column

```
 declare @temp table(name varchar(1), virtual int, message varchar(2))

 insert into @temp
 values('a'       ,1 ,    'm1'),
 ('a',       1 ,    'm2'),
 ('a',       0 ,    'm3'),
 ('a',       0 ,    'm4'),
 ('b',       1 ,    'm5'),
 ('b',       0 ,    'm6'),
 ('c',       0 ,    'm7')

 select tmp2.name, stuff((select ','+message from @temp tmp1
 where
 tmp1.virtual=1
 and tmp1.name=tmp2.name
 for xml path('')),1,1,'') result
 from @temp tmp2
 where tmp2.virtual=1
 group by tmp2.name
```

output:

```
 name   result
 a      m1,m2
 b      m5
```